# How do you count the number of api calls in tidyquant?

Tags: r, api, tidyquant

For example, I'm getting stock prices from yahoo finance using tidyquant in r.

```
library(tidyquant)
tq_get(c("AAPL","AMD"), from = '20222-03-01', to = '2022-03-02')
```

This will result in 4 rows.

How many api calls does this result in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 api calls.

Each ticker and date combination (from, to) and daily, weekly or monthly data is one api call. The api call is based on quantmod's `getSymbols.yahoo` which builds the query via `.yahooURL`. This url is a combination of the ticker, from, to, period (daily, weekly, monthly), event (historical data, dividend data or split data).

You can see this in action if you look at the yahoo finance historical data and then look at the download link. E.g. for MSFT: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/history?p=MSFT

1 api call for historical MSFT data:

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/MSFT?period1=1617621728&period2=1649157728&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true

So in your example, 2 queries will be sent to the yahoo servers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is one API call per ticker and day:

```r
tickers <- c("AAPL", "AMD")
from <- "2022-03-01"
to <- "2022-03-02"

length(tickers) * length(seq(as.Date(from), as.Date(to), by = "day"))
#> [1] 4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

However, you can also use much less calls if you like.

Comment: So every row is 1 call? Jesus. I'm doing an assignment and what do you think is an optimal amount of pauses so I don't get blocked? For example 3 seconds per 1000 calls?

Comment: Stack overflow is not for answering assignments.

Comment: I assumed one call per row, because you required to have 4 as the expected output.

Comment: The assignment is making a whole project using shiny. This question is just so that I don't get blocked while making the project. So no need to worry about spoiling answers.